# powershell -match defaulting to garbage

Tags: powershell, match

I have a highly used method that I use to get contents from a file, and then it returns contents between two given parameters.  It works for every other one (about 15 files), but for the one I just added, it's defaulting to garbage text that isn't even in the file read. I've tried re-using the filename being fed to the method, as well as using a different filename.  I've tried using different from/to strings in the file in the area returning the garbage.

This is the method called:

```
#Function to look for method content with to parse and return contents in method as string
#Note that $followingMethodName is where we parse to, as an end string. $methodNameToReturn is where we start getting data to return.
Function Get-MethodContents{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param ( [string]$codePath, [string]$methodNameToReturn, [string]$followingMethodName)
  Process
  {
      $contents = ""
      Write-Host "In GetMethodContents method File:$codePath method:$methodNameToReturn followingMethod:$followingMethodName"  -ForegroundColor Green

      $contents = Get-Content $codePath -Raw #raw gives content as single string instead of a list of strings
      $null = $contents -match  "($methodNameToReturn[\s\S]*)$followingMethodName" ###############?? wrong for just the last one added
      
      Write-Host "File Contents Found: $($Matches.Item(1))" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
      Write-Host "File Contents Found: $($Matches.Item(0))" -ForegroundColor Cyan
      Write-Host "File Contents Found: $($Matches[0])" -ForegroundColor Cyan
      Write-Host "File Contents Found: $($Matches[1])" -ForegroundColor Cyan

      return $Matches.Item(1) 
  }#End of Process
}#End of Function
```

This is the calling code.  The GetMethodContents for FileHandler2 is defaulting to $currentVersion (6000) when it returns, which isn't even in the file being provided.

```
  elseif($currentVersion -Match '^(6000)') #6000
  {   
      $HopResultMap = [ordered]@{}
      $HopResultMap2 = [ordered]@{}
      #call method to return basePathFull cppFile method contents
      $matchFound = Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0] -methodNameToReturn "Build the HOP error map" -followingMethodName "CHop2Windows::getHOPError" #correct match
      #call method to get what is like case info but is map in 6000 case....it's 2 files so 2 maps for 6000
      $HopResultMap = (Get-Contents60 -fileContent $matchFound)  #error map of ex: seJam to HOP_JAM
      $FileHandler = Join-Path -Path $basePathFull -ChildPath "Hop2Windows\XXHandler.cpp"
      $matchFound2 = Get-MethodContents -codePath $FileHandler -methodNameToReturn "XXHandler::populateVec" -followingMethodName "m_Warnings" #matches correctly
      $HopResultMap2 = (Get-Contents60_b -fileContent $matchFound2) #used in foreach
      #sdkErr uses Handler file too but it Get-methodContents is returning 6000 so try diff filename
      $FileHandler2 = Join-Path -Path $basePathFull -ChildPath "Hop2Windows\XXHandler.cpp"
      $matchFound3 = Get-MethodContents -codePath $FileHandler2 -methodNameToReturn "feed from No. 0" -followingMethodName "class CHop2Windows;" # returns 6000-wrong######################??
      $HopResultMap3 = (Get-Contents60_c -fileContent $matchFound3) #used in foreach
      #next need to put these 2 maps together
      #need to test I got matches correct in 6000 map still################
      #combine the maps so can reuse 7000's case/design.  $hopResultMap key is the common tie with $hopResultMap2 and thrown away
      $resultCase = foreach ($key in $HopResultMap.Keys){ 
        [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
          sdkErr      = "HopResultMap3[$key]" # 0x04
          sdkDesc     = "HopResultMap2[$key]" # Fatal Error
          sdkOutErr   = "$($HopResultMap[$key])"
        }
      }
      
  }//else
```

This is with powershell 5.1 and VSCode.

Update (as requested):

```
$pathViewBase = 'C:\Data\CC_SnapViews\EndToEnd_view\' 
$HopBase = '\Output\HOP\'
$basePathFull = Join-Path -Path $pathViewBase -ChildPath $HopBase
$Hop2PrinterVersionDirs = @('Hop2Windowsxx\Hop2Windowsxx.cpp')


...
foreach($cppFile in $Hop2VersionDirs) #right now there is only one
{ 
   $File = @(Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path $basePathFull -ChildPath $cppFile))
```

Update2:

I tried escaping like this with the problematic content returned:

```
$matchFound3 = Get-MethodContents -codePath $FileHandler2 -methodNameToReturn [regex]::Escape("feed from No. 0") -followingMethodName regex[Escape("class CHop2Windowsxx;")
```

and see this error:

> Get-MethodContents : A positional parameter cannot be found that
> accepts argument 'Roll feed from No. 0'.

Comment: What is `$File`?

Comment: see Update above

Comment: Nothing appears to have changed? Assuming `$file` contains file info objects from `Get-ChildItem`, do: `Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0].FullName` instead of `Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0]`

Comment: The filename I'm having an issue with isn't in $File[]. The only change is I'm getting different contents from $FileHandler, which I'm calling $FileHandler2

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that you've forgotten to escape the method names: `$methodNameToReturn = [regex]::Escape($methodNameToReturn);$followingMethodName = [regex]::Escape($followingMethodName)` - otherwise the regex engine will interpret the `.` in `feed from No. 0` as a metacharacter and match _any character_.

Comment: Would I escape them when I'm calling the method, or in the method?

Comment: That's entirely up to you - but the nice thing about doing it inside the method is that you don't need to change it anywhere else then :)

Comment: see Update2 above please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241733/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-michele).

Comment: Garbage text often means encoding problems. Try loading file with `$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)` and try different encodings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was giving it the .cpp filename, but the content I was looking for was in the .h filename.  :\